# maven-javadoc-plugin: How can I exclude resource folders which violate Java package naming conventions?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am trying to generate an aggregated set of javadocs from a collection of related projects, [like so](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-javadoc/blob/83d2fe7f2d546cdc0971f323dfaf56d0089e715d/pom.xml).

In a nutshell, this POM project declares a bunch of dependencies and then uses the `maven-javadoc-plugin`'s `<includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>` option.

Some of the dependencies have a `script-templates` folder in their resources, which gets lumped into the "-sources" JAR by the `maven-source-plugin`.

Unfortunately, it seems the javadoc tool dislikes folders with violate java package naming conventions. So my build ultimately fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:jar (attach-javadocs) on project imagej-javadoc: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "script-templates.Java"
```

I tried adding `<excludePackageNames>script-templates</excludePackageNames>` to the `maven-javadoc-plugin` configuration, but it seemed to have no effect.

Does anyone have ideas how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `fakeClass` source modification?

```
<sourceModifications>
  <sourceModification>
    <className>fakeClass</className>
      <includes>
        <include name="script-templates.java"/>
      </includes>
    </sourceModification>
</sourceModifications>
```

Comment: I tried [this](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-javadoc/commit/40a227ec16f9cc2bf13b534ae42cf47fb263607b). Unfortunately, I still see the same error. Is that what you meant? And where did you find this hack? I couldn't find it anywhere after 5 minutes of searching...

Comment: This bit is from when [it was proposed](http://community.jedit.org/?q=node/view/1663) that jEdit use Maven.

Comment: That thread is ten years old. I think `sourceModifications` must be from Maven 1; it isn't mentioned anywhere in the modern Maven POM reference. What makes you think it is relevant to this issue?

Comment: Well, reading your question I had remembered seeing something that told Maven that something wasn't a real class and shouldn't be compiled; one look through my browser history later, I posted this.